# Check if a class is an instance of list

Tags: java, reflection

I need to get all methods in a class that can return a List and then, check for all those method  what type of List it is.  When I get that type, I need to check if it is an implementation of a particular interface.

I do:

```
Person person = new Person();
Class c = person.class;
for (Method m: c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    // this gets me all the getters
    if (m.getParameterTypes().size() == 0) {
        Class<?> returnType = m.getReturnType()
        if (returnType.equals(java.util.List.class)) {
              // Can get here
              // But how to get the class that is used to parameterise the 
              // list.
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the Class that is used to parameterise a List?

Comment: I don't think you can because of type erasure.

Comment: Use `m.getGenericReturnType()`.

Comment: Can you describe more on what actual problem you are trying to solve and why you need to do this?

Comment: I second @Cratylus question.  This feels like it might be [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What is the ultimate problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `m.getReturnType()`, use [`m.getGenericReturnType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType--).

This gives you back a `Type`. You then need to test if this is an instance of [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html): if it is, cast, and extract the type parameters using `getActualTypeArguments()`.